# Open a keynote file from a phonegap app inside Keynote

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, childbrowser, keynote

Wondering if there is a way to open a keynote file with a phonegap app that would launch Keynote on the iPad if the user had it installed.  I have tried it with the ChildBrowswer plugin, but it only show the simple preview of the keynote and not the actual presentation.

It works if I link directly to a hosted keynote file on a website on safari, because it will shortly show the "Open in Keynote" button in the upper right.  This would be perfect functionality if I could get that to work inside of the childbrowser plugin.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write your own plugin (http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.4.0/guide_plugin-development_index.md.html#Plugin%20Development%20Guide) and use UIDocumentInteractionController (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIDocumentInteractionController_class/Reference/Reference.html) to open the file.

Comment: Thanks robert, I will see if I can get through the plugin process - just curious if the DocumentInteractionController Class does handle keynote files...

Comment: @whodeee - It's really not that difficult and absolutely worth the effort. Especially since many useful Phonegap Plugins are in a very rudimentary state and have to be adapted anyway.